# Use Geckofx in a c# 64-bit Windows Forms Apps

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

In a 64-bit C# window forms app can I use geckofx or there is no such a solution? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the description of the 'geckofx' tag? Or am lost in the woods?

Comment: Yes and describes exactly what I want. Anyway I will make a minor change to the title of question.

Comment: But if it `describes excactly` what you want, what is the question?

Comment: geckofx plays only 32-bit. So the question is if it plays with 64-bit as question says.

Comment: But if you are sure that it only plays in 32-bit, why is there even a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need GeckoFX source code. Build in x64. Then download xulrunner source code from ftp.mozila.org (same version with gecko fx) and build in x64.

An alternative to building GeckoFX from source is to use CorFlags.exe to mark the assemblies as 64bit
(by Tom)

Comment: can you provide the link to download GeckoFX build in x64 ?

Comment: why its not working for me while I try it in visual studio 2013. after converting both libraries in x64, its still not working for me..

Answer (score 1):

There is now [64bit geckofx nuget package.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geckofx45.64/)

Compiling Firefox from source is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Tom's answer worked for me. The only thing I encountered after bumping to 64bit was that I had an issue with include in my .csproj file:

```
<FirefoxDir Include="$(PkgGeckofx45)\content\Firefox\*.*" />
```

this stopped being resolved correctly, and this PkgGeckofx45 was defined nowhere. After 2 trials I've found that `$(PkgGeckofx4564)` works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32442798)