# GeckoFx and XULRunner in a 64bits C# application

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

Similar: [Use Geckofx in a c# 64-bit Windows Forms Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360906/use-geckofx-in-a-c-sharp-64-bit-windows-forms-apps)

I have an application written in C# that it is using the GeckoFx 33 x86 version. I am trying to port the whole application to x86, thus I need the GeckoFx (including XULRunner) to be in 64 bits.

What I have tried:

I created a new empty Solution and downloaded the GeckoFx nuget. I changed the application to be build in x64 and it doesn't work. It shows an error stating that the GeckoFx library is in a BadImageFormat, meaning it's not in 64bit.

I have downloaded the source code for the GeckoFx 33 version and compiled myself. The dll is perfectly created but now I need a XULRunner for the version 33 and 64 bits. I couldn't find it.

What is the standard way to go to install GeckoFX in a 64 bits application? What am I missing?

Comment: I too could not find an existing 64bit xulrunner, but you could perhaps build your own. http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Main_Page seems to have last done it for 31.

However, check out https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0, which is using a firefox distro, and that does have 64 bit versions (e.g. https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.0/win64-EME-free/en-US/).

Answer (score 0):

Xulrunner is embedded in Firefox. You can try to build Xulrunner yourself.

It's actually also my problem, but i couldn't find any solution and cannot build Xulrunner in 64-bit.

Did you find any solution?

Comment: see: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/issues/108/is-there-anyway-to-use-v45-in-64bit-mode